# UITableView Запись-комментарии

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

В общем проблема следующая, у меня есть массив, в котором запись, скажем:

```
"name" : "Key"
"comments" : [],
```

и в нем массив комментариев к записи, каким образом можно отобразить в таблице (списке):

запись, а под ней комментарии, я понимаю что моя запись - это будет секция, а комментарий это строки в секции, но я не могу понять как это реализовать, буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Неужели никто не в курсе? (

Answer (score 1):

если запись - это секция, а комментарии - строки, тогда что-то вроде:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.items.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.items[section][@"comments"] count];
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [MySectionHeader headerWithText:self.items[section][@"name"]];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCommentCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    MyComment *object = self.items[indexPath.section][@"comments"][indexPath.row];
    /*configure cell here */
    return cell;
}
```